# How to calculate days between dates accurately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I wrote the following Python function that takes from the user data in the form of their birth date  and calculates how old they are today and how many more days are remaining until their birthday this year:

```
# %load time_2_bday.py
"""
Created on Thu Feb 20 16:01:33 2020
@author: hussain.ali

"""
import datetime as dt
import pytz
def days_to_birthday():
    ''' this function takes from the user data in the form of their birthdate 
        and calculates how many more days are remaining until their birthday this year'''

    a = (input('Enter the date on which you were born:'))
    b = (input('Enter the month in which you were born:'))
    c = (input('Enter the year in which you were born:'))
    d = '%s%s%s'%(c,b,a)
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    curr_yr = str((now.year))
    td = dt.datetime.today()
    #td.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    birthday = dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d')
    days_old = td - birthday

    if int(b) <= td.month:
        days_to_birthday = td - dt.datetime.strptime('%s%s%s'%(curr_yr,b,a), '%Y%m%d')
        print('You stand', days_old.days//365,'years old today and there are', 365- days_to_birthday.days, 'days remaining until your next birthday!')        
    else:
        days_to_birthday = dt.datetime.strptime('%s%s%s'%(curr_yr,b,a), '%Y%m%d') - td
        print('You stand', days_old.days//365,'years old today and there are',days_to_birthday.days, 'days remaining until your next birthday!')

days_to_birthday()
```

It is working fine **except** for it gives the output of *number of days* one less than the actual number of days remaining until the next birthday, i.e.

> ============= RESTART: C:\Users\hussain.ali\Desktop\time_2_bday.py =============
>   Enter the date on which you were born:10
>   Enter the month in which you were born:05
>   Enter the year in which you were born:1986
>   You stand 33 years old today and there are 74 days remaining until your next birthday!

While the actual number of days remaining until 10th May 2020 is 75.

Is it because February this year has 29 days and I have skipped something that should take this 1 extra day into account?

Can someone also tell me if this script is time aware or naive?

Comment: At the very least this is way overcomplicated. E.g., to construct `birthday`, you should just do `dt.date(int(c), int(b), int(a))`…

Comment: There are only 74 *whole* days until that day starts. Stick to dates, not datetimes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe makes sense... thank you very much!!

Comment: You should be using `date` instead of `datetime`. You just need to construct three `date`s: `birthday` and `today`, and depending on whether `birthday.month` and `birthday.day` are `<` or `>` `today`, you construct a `next_birthday` with `day` and `month` of `birthday` and `year` of `today` or `today.year + 1` (consider that birthdays occurring on leap days will produce an error here). Then you can easily diff between those three dates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking your code apart, I'll demonstrate a more simplified way to achieve this:

```
from datetime import date

year = int(input('Year:'))
month = int(input('Month:'))
day = int(input('Day:'))

birthday = date(year, month, day)
today = date.today()
next_birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year)

if next_birthday < today:
    # birthday for this year has already passed
    next_birthday = next_birthday.replace(year=next_birthday.year + 1)

print('You are', int((today - birthday).days / 365), 'years old')
print('Your next birthday is in', (next_birthday - today).days, 'days')
```

The only thing you need to be aware of here is that birthdays on a leap day will throw errors on the lines where you calculate `next_birthday` if that year isn't a leap year. It's somewhat undefined how to handle this; people whose birthday is on a leap day may typically celebrate one day early then, but some may celebrate a day late. There may be different local laws how the age is legally defined then. You need to define how you'd like to handle that.